# TradingView v1 to v4 iff statements Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to integrate TradingView's stock ATR Stops script, built in Pine Script v1, into a v4 code of my own, and it's causing the error "Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation' for the iff statements below.

Could someone help me translate just these lines into v4 compatible code?

Note: as the post title implies, this code WORKS but in Pine Script v1 only, and I'm trying to adapt it to v4, which I believe requires if else statements rather than iff statements.

```
//@version=1
study(title="ATR Stop", overlay = true)

nATRPeriod = input(5)
nATRMultip = input(2.5)

xATR = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss = nATRMultip * xATR

xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss),
                    iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                        iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))

pos =   iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
            iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0))) 

color = pos == -1 ? red: pos == 1 ? green : blue 

plot(xATRTrailingStop, color=color, title="ATR Trailing Stop")
```

Comment: Pine code is indented in increments of 4 blanks. If code is on the same indent "level", it's considered a separate command. If indented with one more blank, it's considered to be part of the previous line. You should indent your `iff` on the last line with one more blank, just like you did with the `iff` on the 2nd line.

Comment: Thanks I gave this a try but I'm still getting "Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'" on the very first line in the above code :(

Comment: Please update your question to include the complete script, instead of just this code snippet. This will help to investigate the problem.

Comment: Updated to include the complete script 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code for v4 below. Indentation is important.

```
//@version=4
study(title="ATR Stop", overlay = true)

nATRPeriod = input(5)
nATRMultip = input(2.5)

var float   xATRTrailingStop    = na
var int     pos                 = na

xATR                = atr(nATRPeriod)
nLoss               = nATRMultip * xATR

xATRTrailingStop    := iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 
                             max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss), 
                             iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 
                                 min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss), 
                                 iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 
                                     close - nLoss, 
                                     close + nLoss)))

pos                 := iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 
                         1, 
                         iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 
                          -1, 
                          nz(pos[1], 0))) 

atrColor            = pos == -1 ? color.red : pos == 1 ? color.green : color.blue 

plot(xATRTrailingStop, "ATR Trailing Stop", atrColor)
```

Comment: Works like a charm thanks so much would have never figured this out alone! 

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think your problem was the commas you put in the end.
Iff can have 2 possible results, which you put in the first line itself. Then why put the comma ?

Also use proper indentation

```
xATRTrailingStop = iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), max(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close - nLoss)
                   iff(close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), min(nz(xATRTrailingStop[1]), close + nLoss) 
                   iff(close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), close - nLoss, close + nLoss)))
    
    pos =   iff(close[1] < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), 1,
            iff(close[1] > nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0) and close < nz(xATRTrailingStop[1], 0), -1, nz(pos[1], 0)))
```

PS: if this doesn't work, try writing the code again and if possible use the `if else`, you'll be able to see the nest properly. And don't forget to indent

Comment: The above code is TradingView's own code. It works, but in version 1 Pine Script only. I'd like to update it to v4 compatibility. I believe this might require if else but I'm not sure how to do it. Would you be willing to help? Thanks 